# Specflow scenario fails on the line X but says that if has failed on the last line of the scenario

Tags: .net, automation, .net-6.0, specflow

I have a test on Specflow that now fails due to a bug.
Let's say it fails on line 5 of the scenario file, yet failure stacktrace says that it fails on the last line of the scenario (8).

It started happening on upgrade from .NET Framework 4.7.x to .NET 6

So I just want to get correct failure line for .feature file. Any ideas?

**Example of scenario:**

```
Feature: Calculator

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is 50
    And the second number is 70
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be 120
```

**Step definitions:**

```
namespace SpecFlowProject6.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class CalculatorStepDefinitions
    {
        // For additional details on SpecFlow step definitions see https://go.specflow.org/doc-stepdef

        [Given("the first number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheFirstNumberIs(int number)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        [Given("the second number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheSecondNumberIs(int number)
        {
        }

        [When("the two numbers are added")]
        public void WhenTheTwoNumbersAreAdded()
        {
        }

        [Then("the result should be (.*)")]
        public void ThenTheResultShouldBe(int result)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of stacktrace:**

```
System.Exception : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at SpecFlowProject6.StepDefinitions.CalculatorStepDefinitions.GivenTheFirstNumberIs(Int32 number) in C:\Users\Denys_Koreiba\source\repos\SpecFlowProject6\SpecFlowProject6\StepDefinitions\CalculatorStepDefinitions.cs:line 11
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
   at SpecFlowProject6.Features.CalculatorFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
   at SpecFlowProject6.Features.CalculatorFeature.AddTwoNumbers() in C:\Users\Denys_Koreiba\source\repos\SpecFlowProject6\SpecFlowProject6\Features\Calculator.feature:line 8

Given the first number is 50
-> error: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. (0,1s)
And the second number is 70
-> skipped because of previous errors
When the two numbers are added
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then the result should be 120
-> skipped because of previous errors
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

Comment: Did you try updating the SpecFlow extension in Visual Studio, as well as the SpecFlow NuGet packages? Which unit testing provider are you using? Try updating that NuGet package as well, including the package used to generate the test classes from feature files.

Comment: Also try deleting the .vs folder, and all files under the bin and obj directories for all projects in your solution. Delete all feature.cs files. Basically do a "super clean" of the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried with MSTest and with NUnit too. All extensions and nugets have the latest version. Actually I just created a new project to make sure it's no my working project issue and it reproduces. So you can try it too - create a new project and run tests. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my suggestions in my second comment?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes, I tried. Didn't help :( So the question is: does it work for you?

Comment: I have .NET 7 test projects with Visual Studio 2022 that properly mark test failures. Are you sure you don't have something in an `[AfterScenario]` throwing an exception, which then causes the test to fail?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes, I'm sure. I've just created a completely new Specflow Project with its basic steps. I'll try with .NET 7 now. Thanks!

Comment: @GregBurghardt wait, but how you have SpecFlow on .NET 7 if it supports only .NET 6?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Update: I've urged update to .NET 7 still have the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include all step definitions and hooks? And please include the code as plain text, not images.

Comment: @GregBurghardt thanks for you desire to help. I've updated the post adding the code.

Comment: Ok. I'm not seeing the problem here. The standard output clearly indicates the `Given` step threw the exception. The stack trace even refers to line 11 of your step definition file, which is the line that explicitly throws an exception.

Comment: Ok. Hm. I see, the very last line in the stack trace refers to the last step in the feature file. I haven't noticed this before. I've always looked at the standard output or the first line in the stack trace.

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes, I'm talking about the last line

Comment: @GregBurghardt I found a more specific issue. Turns out if in .NET Framework project I'll add specflow.json configuration file it will have the same behaviour. As soon as I remove the specflow.json file it will work as I expect. In .NET projects old config app.config must be changed to specflow.json so probably the mechanism of configuration is changed and this cause different stacktrace handling. Yet, I have no idea how to get wanted behaviour.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm not able to reproduce this using MS Test + SpecFlow + VS 2022 + .NET 7 test project with a specflow.json file. This might be worth creating an example repo in GitHub (or some similar service) and [logging an issue](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues).

Comment: @GregBurghardt if by "cannot reproduce" you mean that removing specflow.json from your .NET 7 project doesn't change anything it's correct, cuz you need .NET Framework to see this change. In .NET 6 or 7 it always works the same and you already noticed that the line at the end of stack trace it wrong. I've created issue on specflow github.

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using? There is usually a NuGet package that converts the feature file into a test class. I wonder if that needs to be updated?

Comment: @GregBurghardt it doesn't matter. I tried NUnit and MS Test too. Latest versions.